# mschart Axe-Y scale values

Tags: mschart

How can i get rid of the fraction point scale in the Axe Y of MS Chart,

I want the values to be 1,2,3,.. etc

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be something like this:

```
var chart = new Chart();
chart.ChartAreas.Add(new ChartArea());

chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "0";
```

Also, see this: [axis formatting](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/MSWinWebChart/thread/8f843a18-c72e-4cc1-9fcc-7ad0d9e39c15/)

Edit:

Mustafa's comment is correct. The above line will redisplay all tick marks on the y-axis formatted as "0". In order to display tick marks at an interval of 1, do as he says:

```
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Interval = 1;
```

Comment: Oh actually this will repeat the values, but you guide me to the solution, this can be accomplished by setting the '.AxisY.LabelStyle.Interval = 1;'. Thanks